# SQLAlchemy: how to extend hybrid attributes?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm working with a MSSQL database with no control over the DB setup nor the (read-only) data in it. One table is represented in SQLAlchemy like this:

```
class pdAnlage(pdBase):
    __tablename__ = "Anlage"
    typ = Column(CHAR(4), primary_key=True)
    nummer = Column(CHAR(4), primary_key=True)
```

In accessing the database, I need a property "name" that is just a concatenation of "typ" and "nummer" with a dot between them. So I did this:

```
    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        return self.typ + '.' + self.nummer
```

Looks simple and works as expected. There are two caveats though, one general and one special. The general one: The table is quite big, and i'd like to make  queries against Anlage.name, like this:

```
db.query(Anlage).filter(Anlage.name.like('A%.B'))
db.query(Anlage).filter(Anlage.name == 'X.Y')
```

This works but it is inefficient as the SQL server first has to concatenate all "typ" and "nummer" columns of the (large) table before doing the test. So I've defined a classmethods like this one:

```
    @classmethod
    def name_like(self, pattern):
        p = pattern.split('.', 2)
        if len(p) == 1 or not p[1]:
            return self.typ.like(p[0])
        else:
            return and_(self.typ.like(p[0]), self.nummer.like(p[1]))
```

This isn't elegant, but it does the job just fine. It would be nicer to overload "==" and "like()", is there a way to do that?

Now to the special case: Both name and typ columns can contain trailing spaces in the DB. But the name property must not have spaces, especially not before the dot. So I tried to rewrite the name hybrid property like this:

```
    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        return self.typ.rstrip() + '.' + self.nummer.rstrip()
```

This doesn't work because SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to translate the rstrip() python method to the MSSQL RTRIM() function. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [custom comparator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators) that handles string operands in a special way (and others as necessary):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import Comparator

_sep = '.'


def _partition(s):
    typ, sep, nummer = s.partition(_sep)
    return typ, nummer


class NameComparator(Comparator):

    def __init__(self, typ, nummer):
        self.typ = typ
        self.nummer = nummer
        super().__init__(func.rtrim(typ) + _sep + func.rtrim(nummer))

    def operate(self, op, other, **kwgs):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            typ, nummer = _partition(other)
            expr = op(self.typ, typ, **kwgs)

            if nummer:
                expr = and_(expr, op(self.nummer, nummer, **kwgs))

            return expr

        else:
            # Default to using the "slow" method of concatenating first that
            # hides the columns from the index created for the primary key.
            return op(self.__clause_element__(), other, **kwgs)
```

and use it with your hybrid attribute:

```
class pdAnlage(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Anlage"
    typ = Column(CHAR(4), primary_key=True)
    nummer = Column(CHAR(4), primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        return self.typ.rstrip() + _sep + self.nummer.rstrip()

    @name.comparator
    def name(cls):
        return NameComparator(cls.typ, cls.nummer)
```

Comment: Wow, cool! I expected to have to drill down to actual (DB-specific) SQL code, but this is much better (had to lose the rstrip() bits in hybrid_property of course). What I don't understand is this: It works as expected, but when I print out the generated SQL I don't see any rtrim function calls. Just the two comparisons on typ and nummer. Why is that?

Comment: I didn't see those in use in your own implementation, so I skipped them, but if you do want them, add them in the `operate()` method. The calls to `rtrim()` in `__init__()` are used in forming the hybrid's expression, when used as an attribute to select.

Comment: Just note that if you add the RTRIM calls around the columns when comparing, you again hide them from the primary key index.

Comment: Good point, I won't include the rtrim for the comparing bit. Now that my code works as desired I will have to try and understand the documentation on WHY it does.